# Is sys module built into Cpython interpreter?

Tags: memory, module, resources, sys

How much memory, if any, is used when importing the sys module?

Does the CPython interpreter allocate memory resources when I import the sys module, or are its functions and data permanently in memory? Since the module is quite low level, and since (I believe) it is implemented in C, it seems possible that it is built into the interpreter -- and is therefore always in memory. But if not, approximately how much additional memory is taken up when importing it? And if it is built in, does that indeed mean that little extra memory is used when importing it?

Knowing the resources used by sys will help me decide whether or not to import it when I only need it for some non-critical purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No additional memory is used when you import the sys module. As you guessed, the sys module is created as soon as you create the interpreter, [you can see this happening during interpreter creation in the cpython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0710d754255e731e6fcc3f206b51db6156da17c8/Python/pylifecycle.c#L809).